# Connection error with MariaDB under WSL (Debian)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I am using latest Windows 11 build and installed WSL 2 (Debian) for development purpose.
To try out a project, I need to install and configure MariaDB under my WSL Debian system. I have installed MariaDB 10.6.5 fine with no errors, but during initial setup process, I am having issues with connecting to MySQL. When I give following command:

> sudo mysql_secure_installation

it's showing me error that
**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

I also tried following command:

> sudo mysql_secure_installation --protocol=tcp

But it's showing error again
**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'localhost' (115)**

What's the issue here? How to connect with MySQL under WSL 2?

*Note: I don't have MySQL/MariaDB installed under Windows host, only WSL (Debian) has it installed.*

Comment: As I said, no MySQL client or anything on my windows machine. It's a freshly installed Windows machine and only WSL installed. I also tried the method of connecting with the IP of WSL (Debian) found by ifconfig, something like 172.31.xx.xx, but it also returns same error - ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 172.31.xx.xx (115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after stating mariadb service, instead of mysql

```
sudo service mariadb start
```